# wpf: how to bind text box to custom virtual keyboard?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding

I am designing a custom virtual keyboard based on stack panel and including bunch of buttons in it for multi touch purposes. The keyboard will be defined as a resource in order to be used on different windows,canvases etc. My question is that, how to bind the focused text box to this custom virtual keyboard?

Best regards.

Celil

Answer (score 0):

For sending input you may use SendInput WinAPI function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx (you may get PInvoke import for that here: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendInput.html )

But the main problem is how to avoid losting focus of external textbox when clicking button on virtual keyboard window.